# Python Validation Checks do not correctly work

Tags: python, validation

I have some validation checks for my menu which seem to be repeating the error message and I have spent so long staring at this error I seem to have gone blank!

I am running a file called student_class (not a class but just the file name) and as any menu validation if the user enters the incorrect choice I want it to display the error message and then re-display the menu etc etc.

The validation code is:

```
def ValidateMenuChoice(choice):
  validchoice = False
  Num = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  while validchoice == False :
    if choice not in Num:
      print("Invalid choice, please try again.")
      display = menu.Menu("Student")
      display.printMenu()
      GetMenuChoice()
      ValidateMenuChoice(choice)
    else:
      validchoice = True
  return choice
```

Is there a simple mistake I am making or could it be more complex? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

GetMenuChoice function:

```
def GetMenuChoice(): #Gets users menu choice
  MenuChoice = int(input())
  print()
  return MenuChoice
```

ANSWER EDIT:

Using a few answers below (thanks!) I had to just add main(choice) into my code as seen below:

```
def ValidateMenuChoice(choice=None):
  Num = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  while True:
    if choice not in Num:
      print("Invalid choice, please try again.")
      display = menu.Menu("Student")
      display.printMenu()
      choice = GetMenuChoice()
      main(choice) #Added to make it work
    else:
      return choice
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You are never updating `choice`, so if the initial choice is wrong, there is no way to fix it. Perhaps you meant `choice = GetMenuChoice()`?

Comment: @lyschoening I did what you suggested and it seemed to break out of the repeat but it does not seem to continue to the re-entered choice. So hopefully with some tweaking as well as the answer provided below I will be able to get it working thanks!

Comment: you should also post the `GetMenuChoice` function.

Comment: I posted the GetMenuChoice function but as this file is accessed via a menu in another file I believe this is what is causing the issue?

Comment: Don't try to use recursion here. Calling `ValidateMenuChoice` in the same function is just plain wrong.

Comment: Yeah sorry.. still learning! It seems to work well now but it still doesn't go to the correct function on the re-entering

Comment: You make a lot of recursive function calls when you should really be assigning the results of function calls. Your problem will probably be fixed if you replace the other return with `main(choice)` as well, but it is not good practice to couple functions like that. You should make a call to `ValidateMenuChoice` from within `main`, and grab the `return` value from in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting both an iterative and a recursive approach, but you are not tracking your `choice` and `validchoice` variables properly.

For a proper recursive approach, get rid of your `while` and add a `return`:

```
def ValidateMenuChoice(choice):
  Num = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  if choice not in Num:
      print("Invalid choice, please try again.")
      display = menu.Menu("Student")
      display.printMenu()
      choice = GetMenuChoice()
      return ValidateMenuChoice(choice)
  return choice
```

An iterative approach would look like this:

```
def ValidateMenuChoice(choice=None):
  Num = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  while True:
    if choice not in Num:
      print("Invalid choice, please try again.")
      display = menu.Menu("Student")
      display.printMenu()
      choice = GetMenuChoice()
    else:
      return choice
```

Comment: This seems to be working but it does not go to the function assigned to the number when I re-enter the choice

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make a simple tweak:

```
choice = GetMenuChoice()
```

At the moment, you never update `choice`, so it recurses indefinitely.

More broadly, I would probably take an iterative approach, and avoid using a flag (`validchoice`):

```
def GetValidMenuChoice():
    display = menu.Menu("Student")
    while True:
        display.printMenu()
        choice = GetMenuChoice()
        if choice in range(1, 7):
            return choice
        else:
            "Invalid choice, please try again."
```

Ideally, I would remove the hard-coded `range(1, 7)` and make that dependent on the `Menu`, but I can't tell from what you've posted whether that would be possible.